# German character ß encoding in Livelink using C#

Tags: c#, api, unicode, encoding, livelink

I have folder name that contains German special character such äÄéöÖüß.The following screenshot display contents of LiveLink server.

[image]

I want to extract folder from Livelink server using C#.

valueis obtained from LLserver.

```
  var bytes = new List<byte>(value.Length);           

         foreach (var c in value)
         {
             bytes.Add((byte)c);                 
         }           

        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

Finally, the result is äÄéöÖü�x .where ß is seen as box character '�x'. All other characters present in folder name are decoded successfully/properly except the ß character.

I am just wondering why the same code works for all other German special characters but not for ß.

Could anybody help to fix this problem in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "LLServer" ? What type of array is `value` ?

Comment: LLServer is LiveLink Server, which is also known Content Server.

Comment: And what type of array is `value` ? Is it `int[] value` ? Or what is it ?

Comment: value is a c# string, which is obtained from LiveLink API com.opentext.api.LLValue.

Comment: The symbol “�” indicates character-level data error, in this case some bytes that do not even formally conform to the definition of the UTF-8 format. Can you show what the raw data, as numeric values of bytes, is here? (I suspected that the offending character is not really the common “ß” but its rare uppercase equivalent “ẞ”, but this shouldn’t be a problem in UTF-8.)

Comment: The byte value of ẞ is 223

Comment: Which version of Livelink or Content Server are working with? There is a patch for version 9.7.1 available.

Comment: Livelink server Version: 10.0.0
 Update Number: 10
 Build Number: 21

Comment: This is issue is due to Livelink server encoding. I changed the encoding method to UTF-8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin panel of server  Livelink/livelink.exe?func=admin.sysvars
and set  Character Set: UTF-8

and code section change as follow

```
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value); 
        var retValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You guessed your encoding to be UTF8 and it obviously is not. You will need to find out what encoding the byte stream really represents and use that instead. We cannot help you with that, you will have to ask the sender of said bytes.

Comment: The encoding of the LiveLink Server is in UTF-8.

Comment: Which version of Livelink or Content Server are working with? There is a patch for version 9.7.1 available.